# Как открыть форму модально?

Tags: c#

Находясь в коде формы 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настоятельно рекомендую пользоваться поиском по MSDN.

[Form.ShowDialog - метод](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c7ykbedk.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, почитал помогло. Совсем новичок в C#. Второй день изучаю только.